# RabbitMQ source code - How do rabbitmq-boot-steps work?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am new to erlang and rabbitmq and started going through RabbitMQ codebase. I find that in rabbit.erl start/2 function implemented but seems like start/0 or boot/0 is the function which needs to be called for rabbitMQ start-up. Apologies for a very basic question but really appreciate any help in understanding code flow for RabbitMQ specially for start-up and rabbit-boot-step process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a URL to the source code you are looking at? I think I understand what you are asking but some code would help solidify things in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMQ boot process is documented here: https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbit-internals/blob/master/rabbit_boot_process.md

I'm curious to know why you want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The RabbitMQ file you are looking at `rabbit.erl` implements the [Application behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html). This means that when the Erlang VM is told to start the `rabbit` application it will look for a .app file(RabbitMQ's is in `ebin/rabbit_app.in`). On line 16 you can see that the `rabbit` is the module responsible for starting the application. Erlang assumes the module implements the application behavior (if it didn't you would definitely run into errors). Once Erlang has everything setup it invokes the `start/2` callback in `rabbit.erl`. This in turn calls `rabbit_sup:start_link/0`. I have never used RabbitMQ before so I am unsure what happens after that but most likely the supervisor starts all the other supervisors and worker processes needed for RabbitMQ to function.

As for `start/0` and `boot/0`, they are not Erlang callback functions. They are custom functions created by the RabbitMQ engineers. I imagine these functions are used to start the application in specific scenarios (e.g. testing, boot the application in the interpreter during development, etc...).

Hope this helps! Always look for the `behaviour` module attribute (`-behaviour(application).`) when inspecting an Erlang module. Once you know what behavior a module implements you can look up that behavior ([erlang application behavior](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=erlang%20application%20behavior)) and learn a lot more about how things work.

Comment: Oh yeah... and Erlang uses british spelling for the word behavior. So always write `-behaviour` when defining module behaviors :)

Comment: Thanks. I am certainly missing something as I did look at rabbit_sup.erl and start_link/2 and init/1 functions implemented in rabbit_sup.erl but it is not clear how all the other processes are starting. Init/1 function  in rabbit_sup looks like init([]) -> {ok, {{one_for_all, 0, 1}, []}}. - no child specifications are mentioned in this call.

Comment: Yes. That doesn't do anything. `run_boot_steps/1` is called after that by `start/2` and then `run_boot_steps/1` calls `run_step/3` a number of times (around line 366 in rabbit.erl). I imagine that's where all the other processes are started. The code does look a little difficult to follow. If I answered your original question consider marking it accepted.

Comment: @Stratus3D RabbitMQ doesn't start like a standard OTP app, so many things don't apply here. See my answer or this link in any case https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbit-internals/blob/master/rabbit_boot_process.md

Comment: @Stratus3D also the start and boot functions are actually used for booting RabbitMQ, they are not related to testing or any of those scenarios